# What is the most severe punishment a priest could have in history for violating his vows of celibacy?

Tags: religion, catholic-church

I am doing a research about this topic, because I wanted to know if at some point in the history of Chirstian Church (specially the Catholic Chuch) would have a punishment for priests violating their vows of celibacy that could ruin their life completely, which could be in a time when the Catholic Church wasn’t tolerant to this behavior.

By violating their vow of celibacy, I mean having relationships or sex with adult woman. And by ruining a life, I mean the biggest punishment a priest could have received in history.
I’m looking for historical references for cases like these.

Comment: Like most SE sites, we prefer that the question include some evidence that you've tried to solve the question.  What research have you done? Does [WIkipedia:Celibacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Celibacy#Christianity) answer the question?  "ruin his life" is rather subjective, but it looks like you're actually interested in "What is the most severe punishment a priest could have for violating his vows?" - that's going to be a political question, but is much more objective.  Welcome to the site.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace I’ve retitled the questions based on what you explained to me, I want the que question to be objective and less subjective, thank you. I’ve searched on Wikipedia, but couldn’t find a solid subject about this topic.

Comment: Being laicized means certainly ruining completely his life **as a priest**, even if he can be happy and  good catholic afterwards, and marry his girl. This still happens, and they may find lay life difficult (where can he go w/ a philosophy/theology degree? the diocese will not re-hire him). But in the middle ages up to XIX c. there were many priests who fathered bastard children and helped to raise them, with no lasting consequences beyond repentance. Specially when the number of priests were much larger, some were underemployed, and/or did not have good technical and/or spiritual formation.

Comment: You're asking about violating celibacy right? Murder, arson, treason and so on would be against his vows but he would likely receive the same punishments as a layman for them.

Comment: What's worse than eternal damnation?

Comment: That's a problem for future @Spencer. And what, exactly, has future Spencer ever done for you?

Comment: The quality of the comments would be improved if people knew the difference between celibacy and chastity.

Comment: I'm sooo tempted to say "Contracting syphilis?".

Comment: Adultery has been published by civil authorities (as well as by church authorities exerting control over the civilian population) at various times in history, up to and including by the death penalty. Are you excluding civil penalties, because for severity it's hard to beat death? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adultery

Comment: @StuartF, for much of history in much of the area where the Catholic Church operated, a priest would not have been punished by the civil authorities.  In an early example of the separation of church and state, priests and other ecclesiastical figures were (at least nominally) under the sole authority of the Church.

Comment: ?? Nobody can find a single example of a priest being punished for violating vows?  I was sure I could find one, but I came up blank.  SOmeone has to be more skilled than I am.